# django queryset group by field

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

## i have a listview and want to group by based on foreign key id

views.py

---

```
class SelectListView(ListView):
    model=MyModel
    template_name = "/select_list.html"
    context_object_name = 'selectlist'
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all().values('ItemType_id')

    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(SelectListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['range'] = range(context["paginator"].num_pages)
        return context
```

---

models.py

---

```
class ItemType(models.Model):
       ItemType=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=40)
class MyModel(models.Model):
       Type=models.ForeignKey(ItemType)
       ItemName=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=40)
```

## Question: I would like to group by the queryset by ItemType_id in the MyModel

### Expectation: select * from  MyModel group by ItemType_id

Comment: The .values('Type') is showing foreign key but i need the value of that foreign key

Comment: read all my answer and i give you good tutorial linked to

Comment: i have edit my answer ! this help you ?

Comment: rakwen, i think there is problem with django some bug. both queries result in foreign key id instead of ItemType string

Comment: No no no no ! I know it's possible but not for this current usecases. Begin: what do you want to do whit your model suppose you have ModelA and ModelB ?

Comment: i want to show unique value in listview of ModelB which the column1 is foreign key of ModelA and when select the related row in the template then it will generate a formset in the template of that specific column1.     example   Model A   (id, Field1(String),Field2(String)) ModelB(id,Field1,Field2(Foriegnkey(ModelA)) but as per your query the listview shows id value of ModelA but i need string of Field1 of ModelA

Comment: aahhhh ok ! you must use distinct

Comment: suppose you have ModelA(models.Model): name = models.Charfield(...) description=models.TextField(...) and ModelB (models.Model): name = models.CharField(...) modela = models.ForeignKeys(ModelA) <<<<<------- that's correct ?

Comment: Now you want all modelB that's first and unique reference for ForeignK key. <<<<<<----- it's correct ?

Comment: your queryset seen like: qs = ModelB.objects.distinct('modela') <<<<----- it's correct ?

Comment: Thanks you have given me some idea to resolve this matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must doing something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

MyModel.objects.values('Type').annotate(dcount=Count('Type'))

MyModel.objects.values('Type__id').annotate(dcount=Count('Type__id'))
```

you can also read [this document can help you....](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/12/06/how-to-create-group-by-queries.html)
good luck!